# Modify custom option of product in cart

Tags: magento-1.9, php, checkout, cart, quote

I have this code in checkout/cart/item/default.phtml

```
$allProductOptions = $_item->getProduct()->getTypeInstance(true)>getOrderOptions($_item->getProduct());
    $productOptions = $allProductOptions['info_buyRequest'];
```

And in `$productOptions` I have custom option saved from product page: `$productOptions['my_option']`. How can I update that option?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the code above, `$_item` refers to an instance of `Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Item`, so you can alter the buyRequest with the code below:

```
$buyRequest = $_item->getOptionByCode('info_buyRequest');
$buyRequestArr = unserialize($buyRequest->getValue());
$buyRequestArr['whatever_you_like'] = 'some_value';
$buyRequest->setValue(serialize($buyRequestArr))->save();
```

However I'd definitely not advise altering the buyRequest from a phtml file, if you want to add data in to the buyRequest or change existing data, you should do so via an event observer by listening for `checkout_cart_product_add_after`, which supplied you with the quote item, so you can set data on the buyRequest like so:

```
public function checkoutCartProductAddAfter(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();
    $buyRequestArr = array();
    if ($buyRequest = $item->getProduct()->getCustomOption('info_buyRequest')) {
        $buyRequestArr = unserialize($buyRequest->getValue());
    }
    $buyRequestArr['whatever_you_like'] = 'some_value';
    $buyRequest->setValue(serialize($buyRequestArr))->save();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function __construct(
       
        \Magento\Framework\Serialize\Serializer\Json $serialize
    )
    {
      
        $this->serialize = $serialize;
    } 
 public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
       
        $item = $observer->getQuoteItem();  
        $buyRequest = $item->getOptionByCode('info_buyRequest');
        $buyRequestArr =  $this->serialize->unserialize($buyRequest->getValue());
        $buyRequestArr['tester'] = 1;
        $buyRequest->setValue($this->serialize->serialize($buyRequestArr))->save(); 
        return $this;
    }
```